# How to use SSH to access several machines?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

Now I can use the following script to access one single machine.

```
    ssh machine01 cat test.sh
```

But now I have more than 30 machines that need to be accessed. All of their names' format is `machine01, machine02, ..., machine30`.

How could I using `for` statement to achieve it?
Something like:

```
for num in [from 01 to 30]
do
  ssh es-data2023+num cat /data/restart.sh
done
```

Comment: This isn't a tutorial service, there are many sites that show how to write for loops in bash.

Comment: `for num in {01..30}`

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on shell scripting. You don't even know the basics like how to use variables. You have to put a `$` before the variable name: `"es-data2023$num"`

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar already explained you could use `{01..30}` in `bash` which will expand to the complete number sequence, so a working script could be as follows:

```
for HOSTID in {01..30}
do
   ssh user@machine$HOSTID "cat /data/restart.sh"
done
```

But if you seriously want to (remote) manage your 30 hosts I would take a good look at Ansible and not try to reinvent the wheel. Ansible also uses SSH so you don't need any other agent on the servers, only install a control node from which you manage them. You can now also run tasks in parallel and keep the results better apart. Not to mention the huge community that continues to develop the possibilities of Ansible.